# How to execute a set of php functions in every page load?

Tags: php, header

My need was to define couple of php functions and call those php functions every time a page is loaded. As of Now I am directly modifying the Head.phtml and Head.php to get it done.

Is there a clean magento way to do this task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the event `controller_action_predispatch` if you want it for all pages, or `controller_action_layout_render_before` if you want your code to be executed only for pages that have output.
[Here is a tutorial on how to create an observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Comment: The aim of php functions was to add some JS code to the page. In this case is Observer is good ? Php functions are not echoing any  html tags though.

Comment: you should be able to use `controller_action_layout_render_before`.

Comment: Actually I was trying to accomplish my work in a stupid way.. What I did earlier was I created an observer for login and set a session variable. And I have injected a set of php functions which will echo set of JS funtions based on the session flags is set in in observer..
Now I think I can do the JS function injections from the Login_observer itself no need of session variable.